# É sempre bom desalocar a memória antes de uma saída "brusca" do programa com a chamada da função exit()?

Tags: c, gerenciamento-de-memória, alocação

Quando eu estava começando a aprender ponteiros e alocação dinâmica de memória em C, me disseram que toda a memória alocada no programa é *desalocada* quando o mesmo é finalizado. Ex:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    int *vet=calloc(10, sizeof(int));

    //...faz alguma coisa com esse vetor

    //assim que o programa é finalizado toda
    //toda a sua memória é desalocada automaticamente...

    return 0;
}
```

E se nós tivermos alocado essa memória em outra função, onde caso ocorresse um erro fosse necessário uma chamada para `exit()`? É recomendável fazer uma desalocação antes de `exit()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A memória alocada pelo programa pertence ao processo; quando o processo morre, todos os recursos utilizados por ele são liberados. Então, um programa pequeno de execução curta pode "relaxar" no gerenciamento de memória sem conseqüências.

Isto não é ideal para programas complexos, que vão executar por longo tempo. Quando se usa uma ferramenta tipo Valgrind para encontrar bugs, ela lista todas as alocações não-liberadas ao final do programa. Aí vai ser difícil diferenciar o que é "leak" e o que é alocação deixada de propósito.

Como todo programa grande foi um dia um programa pequeno e despretensioso, é bom começar fazendo a coisa certa desde o começo.

Answer (score 6):

Veja a documentação da função [`exit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit). De fato ela faz alguma limpeza quando é chamada, inclusive pode registrar algumas coisas para serem executadas quando ela é chamada. Se precisa que algo seja executado deve chamá-la. Mas lembre-se que a aplicação pode quebrar antes e ela não ser chamada mesmo que você queira.

Fora esta chama extra ela não faz nada demais. Sua aplicação não é dona da memória alocada por ela e o sistema operacional liberará tudo ao final do processo, então não importa onde aloque tudo será liberado.

Se tiver conexões em aberto é função de cada serviço perceber que não tem mais nada comunicando com ele e encerrar. Claro, é tudo controlado pelo sistema operacional de alguma forma e ele fará o encerramento de um jeito conveniente, mesmo que não ideal.

Por padrão entenda que tudo o que você aloca, deve desalocar o mais cedo possível, mas nunca antes de que deveria, e cada recurso adquirido externamente seja liberado (conexões por exemplo). Um código que não faz essas liberações cedo é um código errado por definição, até mesmo quando ele não causa erro. Todo `malloc()` ou algo semelhante deve ser pareado com um `free()`.

Por isso programadores de C sabem que, de forma geral, não deve alocar memória em outras funções, a alocação ocorre no primeiro lugar que ela precisa e assim a pessoa sabe que precisa dar um `free()` ali, inclusive com controle para ter uma saída desta função por apenas um lugar. Gerenciar memória em C é extremamente difícil e por isso só use esta linguagem se tem total comprometimento com isto. Vá para outra linguagem se deseja facilidade para gerenciar memória. Porque complica muito quando não dá para manter esse controle simples de alocar/desalocar dentro da função, e tem vários casos assim, onde a alocação depende do tempo de vida de um objeto e não da função. Por isso uma das melhores invenções da computação foi o coletor de lixo.

Então é recomendável desalocar assim que possível e raramente precisa chamar `exit()`. Ela não faz o que você acha.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: No quarto parágrafo, deveria ser: "mas nunca antes do que **deveria**"?

Comment: @JéfBueno é, fica melhor.